# Где можно найти описание win32com.client на русском?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pywin32

Я нашёл интересную библиотеку win32com.client, но не знаю как ей пользоваться. Подскажите, пожалуйста, где можно найти подробное описание: документацию или статью на русском языке. Спасибо

Comment: Стоит знать английский хотя бы на уровне чтения документации

Comment: Вот вам пример использования https://learndataanalysis.org/create-a-date-picker-widget-for-your-excel-spreadsheet-pyqt5-tutorial/ , но без английского никак!

Comment: Ищите документацию по WinApi. Проблема в том, что оно для языков C/C++. Так что помимо английского, еще неплохо было бы и их знать. Набор и способ вызова функций и типов будет совпадать скорее всего

Comment: Спасибо, но всё же хотелось бы на русском...